# string modifying function: return void or char*?

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

For example:

```
void foo1(char *buffer) {
    buffer[0] = 'a';
}

char *foo2(char *buffer) {
    buffer[0] = 'a';
    return buffer;
}
```

When i want to modify a string I could do:

```
mystr[] = "foobar";
foo1(mystr);
printf("%s",mystr);
```

or using the return value:

```
mystr[] = "foobar";
char *mystr2;
mystr2 = foo2(mystr);
printf("%s",mystr2);
```

I'm a bit confused by the second way: mystr and mystr2 are pointing to different locations but holding the same string. I thought foo2 will copy the address of the modified mystr to mystr2 when returning. What happens instead?

The second question is: Which way of modifying a string is more standard?

Comment: In the second example `mystr` is modified, and `mystr2` is pointing to `mystr`. Try printing `mystr` in the second example as well.

Comment: Not clear and troo broad. One question per question.

Comment: As for your second question, the answer is: Both, and none. Which one is "best" (highly subjective) depends on your use-case. With the second you can do e.g. `printf("%s", foo2(mystr))` which might be useful in *some* situation, but not in others.

Comment: @Olaf - The question(s) are clear enough, and so closely related as to not violate whatever rule it is you are quoting.

Comment: @ryyker: The second question is not related, but asking for opinions. I said it is too broad, because there can be recommendations depending on use-case. I'm, fine if you call it "opinion based" therefore.

Comment: "*mystr and mystr2 are pointing to different locations*" they don't, but to the same.

Comment: While "triaging", this question showed up as test for a "good" question; but I actually agree with @ryyker; thus I put a question on meta regarding thi question ( http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342059/is-this-is-a-good-example-for-triage-test ) ... so dont be surprised when all of a sudden, downvotes, upvotes, close votes come in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which way of modifying a string is more standard?

Standard C string functions declared in the header `<string.h>` usually return pointer to the target string. This allows to chain string functions together. For example relative to your second function definition you could write

```
printf("%s", foo2(mystr));
```

and the statement outputs the modified source string.

In this code snippet

```
char mystr[] = "foobar";
char *mystr2;
mystr2 = foo2(mystr);
printf("%s",mystr2);
```

the character array `mystr[]` passed to the function as an argument is implicitly converted to pointer to its first character.  And the same address is returned from the called function that is the pointer to the first character of the array. Thus after this statement

```
mystr2 = foo2(mystr);
```

the pointer `mysstr2` also points to the first character of the character array `mystr`.

The function `printf` can be called either like

```
printf("%s",mystr);
```

or like

```
printf("%s",mystr2);
```

because the same address is passed to the function in the both cases and again the character array passed to the function `printf` in the first case is implicitly converted to pointer to its first character.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend

```
char *foo( char *str );
```

You can always ignore the returned value, and it's more flexible.  You can't use

```
void foo( char *str );
```

as a function parameter:

```
int someFunc( char *val );
...
int rc = someFunc( foo( data ) );
```

Comment: Using the result of a function that returns a pointer as a function parameter can be really bad. And is quite ugly too, makes the code harder to read, and other things too. I don't understand why some programmers care so much about making the code unreadable for nothing. Like saying "*fewer variables*", what is the benefit of that?

Comment: Let's consider `strcat`. From the readability point of view, we'd rather not have it at all: `print(a + b)`. But in C we have no choice, we have to write `strcat(a,b)`. Now if `strcat` was a void function, we'd have to write: `strcat(a,b); print(a)` See the problem? The intent is not very clear here. We write exactly HOW we do things, but the WHAT we're doing has to be reconstructed. Whereas `print(strcat(a,b))` comes much closer to expressing WHAT we're trying to do.

Comment: Upvoted this answer: it replies exactly what was asked, without too many words.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi *Using the result of a function that returns a pointer as a function parameter can be really bad. And is quite ugly too*  That's just one example of the flexibility returning a `char *` provides.  Returning `char *` allows the function to do *everything* the `void` function does - and then a whole lot more.

Comment: ditto to @linuxfan's comment.  Clear and concise.